# How to make the selected value in @Html.DropDownListFor as following code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

the following code populates the dropdown list for 1-31 under the date dropdown in my asp web.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.eDate,
    Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem 
        { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }))
```

Now I am struggling to have a value in that dropdown preselected (e.g. i want the current date is an selected value). I assume today is 3 and then I have added the code to check if it is 3 and set the value of the Selected property accordingly... It does not work - no selected attribute in `<option>` when I view the source in browser.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.eDate, 
    Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem 
        { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString(), Selected = i == 3 }))
```

Can expert enlighten me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it work for me
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var mymodel = new MyModel() { 
        eDate = DateTime.Now.Day
    };
    return View(mymodel);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
model => model.eDate,
Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem 
    { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }))
```