# Set Default Date with DropdownListFor using Enumerable Range

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

i'm trying set into dropdown's current date i'm tried many variants how to achieve this.. so here is my sample code..

```
@{  var days = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).
        Select(i => new SelectListItem {Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString(), Selected = i == DateTime.Now.Day}).ToList();

        var month = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).
        Select(i => new SelectListItem {Value = i.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i), Selected = i == DateTime.Now.Month}).ToList();

        var years = Enumerable.Range(2000, DateTime.Now.Year - 2000 + 4).
        Select(i => new SelectListItem {Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString(), Selected = i == DateTime.Now.Year}).ToList();
}
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SDay, days)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SMonth, month)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SYear, years)
```

as you can see i set Today in Selected option for day, month and year, debugger show me that today day is selected [Debugger](http://postimg.org/image/eh6w9g18d/) but on view day is set at 1

Comment: please don't add code like that to your views, it's very bad practice.

Comment: i undertand that, but for now it's not necessarily...

Comment: @user2302128 did u inspect your html with developer tool to check whether the option with value '27' or upon the current date is selected or not? Since the code just works fine for me.

Comment: of course i check that..  but it just fill dropdown with dates from 1 to 31..

Comment: oh, i found solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200835/how-to-make-the-selected-value-in-html-dropdownlistfor-as-following-code)